# Combining Field Values (Name)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

The following will select the name of a user who votes positively on an item and then put it in a comma separated string.

```
 var string = string.Join(", ", comment.CommentVote.Where(v=> v.Vote == true).Select(v => v.User.FirstName).ToArray());
```

I want to be able to get the first and last name, put them together, and then list them out in a comma separated list.

Context: I am trying to create something similar to Facebook:

```
 John Doe and 25 others like this
```

Where "25 others" provides a list of users on hover. I can loop through the users who voted and get the first and last names, concatenate them, and then add a comma, it just seems like there should be something simpler that lets me avoid the foreach loop.

Comment: Can't you just do `v.User.FirstName + " " + v.User.LastName`? And `== true` is usually something to avoid, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate them:

```
var str = string.Join(", ", 
                      comment.CommentVote
                             .Where(v=> v.Vote)
                             .Select(v => v.User.LastName + " " + v.User.FirstName));
```

Besides you don't need to call `ToArray()` explicitly, as `string.Join` has an overload accepting `IEnumerable<T>`. And you cannot have a variable with the name `string`, as it's an alias for type `System.String`.

Comment: Well, you can concatenate them anyway you like to (`string.Concat`, `string.Format`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can just join the to value you want in the select statement.

```
var results = string.Join(", ", comment.CommentVote.Where(v=> v.Vote)
              .Select(v => string.Format("{0} {1}", v.User.FirstName, v.User.LastName)));
```

**EDIT: Opps sorry, Konstantin Vasilcov already answered**